# PHP - Two server logins: localhost / localhost:3306 - control user has no access

Tags: php, mysql, database, configuration, phpmyadmin

I updated my Linux 14.04 LTS to 18.04 and had to downgrade the PHP 7.2 to 7.0 as I need to run some software which is not capable of the preinstalled PHP 7.2. I used PHP 5 so far.

After I got everything runnning now, MySQL, Apache and PHP I created a new database and now I get a Notification that the controluser can't be connected and that 'pmp'@localhost has denied access.

This appears when I log into server localhost.
If I choose localhost:3306 everything works fine. But I do not know why I have two server logins?

Can I somehow delete the localhost-access and only enable localhost:3306?

Any idea what I have to do?
I'm a database newbie. Best

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using, and which version of PHP did you upgrade from?  It's possible that your users were set up using the old password types, which the new versions of PHP don't use.

Comment: @gabe3886 So I use MySQL 5.7.23 and PHP 7.0. I actualised my question. But where do I have to set up password types, php config file? I'm still confused, why I get two server logins...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I comment these lines in my config.inc.php everything runs like expected and I'll get only one server account where I can login.

```
/**
 * phpMyAdmin configuration storage settings.
 */

/* User used to manipulate with storage */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = '';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlport'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pmapass';

/* Storage database and tables */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';
/* Contrib / Swekey authentication */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_swekey_config'] = '/etc/swekey-pma.conf';
```